# ${n\choose1}+3{n\choose3}+5{n\choose5}+...$ in closed form

Tags: combinatorics

How can I evaluate ${n\choose1}+3{n\choose3}+5{n\choose5}+...$ in closed form?

Binomial theorem?  Is that what I'm suppose to use?  I'm not really understanding this.

Answer (score 10):

By the Binomial Theorem, we have 
$$\frac{(1+x)^n -(1-x)^n}{2}=\binom{n}{1}x +\binom{n}{3}x^3+\binom{n}{5}x^5+\cdots .$$
Differentiate with respect to $x$, and set $x=1$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$(2r+1)\cdot \binom n{2r+1}=\frac{(2r+1)n!}{(2r+1)!(n-2r-1)!}$$

$$=\frac{(2r+1)n!}{(2r+1)\cdot (2r)!(n-1-2r)!}=n\cdot\binom {n-1}{2r}$$

Now, we know $(1+x)^{n-1}=\sum_{0\le r\le n-1}\binom {n-1}rx^r$

Putting $x=1,(1+1)^{n-1}=\sum_{0\le r\le n-1}\binom {n-1}r$

$x=-1\implies (1-1)^{n-1}=\sum_{0\le r\le n-1}\binom nr(-1)^r$

Adding we get, $2^{n-1}=2\cdot \sum_{0\le r\le n-1}\binom {n-1}{2r} $

Comment: @user82526, my pleasure

Comment: How does that help? I don't see it.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, so the sum will be $\frac n2\cdot 2^{n-1}$ right?

Comment: @lab : I didn't say anything. I guess I just got lost in the details but of course it's right.